# python dataclass `__init_subclass__` does not load the fields from subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-dataclasses

Please check the code below

```py
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    a: int = 10

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        for f in dataclasses.fields(cls):
            print("     ", cls, f.name)


print("Defining Subclass B")


@dataclasses.dataclass
class B(A):
    b: int = 100


print("Defining Subclass C")


@dataclasses.dataclass
class C(B):
    c: int = 1000
```

The output is

```
Defining Subclass B
      <class '__main__.B'> a
Defining Subclass C
      <class '__main__.C'> a
      <class '__main__.C'> b
```

I was expecting

```
Defining Subclass B
      <class '__main__.B'> a
      <class '__main__.B'> b
Defining Subclass C
      <class '__main__.C'> a
      <class '__main__.C'> b
      <class '__main__.C'> c
```

Clearly the dunder method `__init_subclass__` does not have the idea of fields in subclass yet as it is not loaded. Please let me know how can I get the expected output.

Comment: In the future, please use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions in addition to any version-specific tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, a decorator works the following way:

```
@some_decorator
class A:
    pass
```

Is equivalent to:

```
class A:
   pass
A = some_decorator(A)
```

So, the `dataclass` decorator *which adds the `__dataclass_fields__` attribute to the class object* hasn't run when `__init_subclass__` runs, because the entire class objects has been created already.

You *could* manually inspect the `__annotations__` (which is what `dataclass` relies on to create `field` objects anyway). Note, you will have to manually inspect all the classes in the MRO, taking care of doing it in reverse order and guarding against potential classes that lack annotations, so something like:

```
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    a: int = 10

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        for klass in  reversed(cls.mro()):
            # in case a base class lacks annotations, e.g. object
            annotations = getattr(klass, '__annotations__', {})
            for name, value in annotations.items():
                print("     ", cls, name, value)

print("Defining Subclass B")


@dataclasses.dataclass
class B(A):
    b: int = 100


print("Defining Subclass C")


@dataclasses.dataclass
class C(B):
    c: int = 1000
```

Could work for you.

The above prints the following output for me:

```
Defining Subclass B
      <class '__main__.B'> a <class 'int'>
      <class '__main__.B'> b <class 'int'>
Defining Subclass C
      <class '__main__.C'> a <class 'int'>
      <class '__main__.C'> b <class 'int'>
      <class '__main__.C'> c <class 'int'>
```

Comment: This solution basically re-implements logics of `dataclasses.dataclass` by reading `__annotations__` on its own, and would incorrectly output pseudo-fields such as `ClassVar` and `InitVar`, which [`dataclasses.fields`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) would correctly exclude. A DRYer approach like @mikenerone's should be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

One easy approach is to call the `dataclass` decorator inside `__init_subclass__()` (and remove the `@dataclass` decorator on the subclasses themselves). This way you force the dataclass initialization before your own logic executes.

```
@dataclasses.dataclass
class A:
    a: int = 10

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        # Note: unlike some decorators, this works
        # because it modifies the class in place.
        dataclasses.dataclass(cls)
        for f in dataclasses.fields(cls):
            print("     ", cls, f.name)


print("Defining Subclass B")


# No "@dataclasses.dataclass" here.
class B(A):
    b: int = 100


print("Defining Subclass C")


# No "@dataclasses.dataclass" here.
class C(B):
    c: int = 1000
```

Comment: how do you know that the `@dataclass` decorator is a no-op if it is run multiple times on a cls that is already decorated? strictly from [personal tests](https://gist.github.com/rnag/9abc4c8b991bb6f918fbee3e45c487fb), this doesn't appear to be the case at all.

Comment: @rv.kvetch This might be something that changed in different Python versions, but I spot-checked 3.7 and 3.10, and in both, `dataclass(ASimpleDataclassClass) is ASimpleDataclassClass` returns `True`. I also tested an existing app with some dataclasses, adding redundant `dataclass()` calls for all of them, and the app continues to function as normal. What kind of side effects are you seeing?

Comment: yes I believe that's totally expected, for example something like `class A: f: str; assert A == dataclass(A)` should always be a success. at least from my understanding, the `@dataclass` decorator does not otherwise overwrite or re-define a class type in any noticeable manner. my point is that, strictly from a *performance* standpoint, it might not be the advisable (or best) approach to use the `@dataclass` decorator judiciously, at least running multiple times on the same class, such as in this scenario.

Comment: check out the gist I linked, I also added comments to clarify what exactly I was testing for.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Ah, I see, so it's only a performance effect. To be fair, I meant "no-op" in the sense of "no change to the result", but I agree with you that A. it's misleading, and  B. performance is enough of a reason to recommend against doing that anyway. So I've updated the answer. Are you good with this change?

Comment: Interesting answer. But looks risky. I will give it a try tough.